# How to get corner points of Rectangle/Ellipse/Path/Line in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, 2d

I'm working on a graphical program and I'd like to get corner points from figures I mentioned in the title. I need them because at those points places, I want to place white, little rectangles that allows me to resize those figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place all your shapes in a Canvas you should be able to get the x and y axis using the `GetLeft` and `GetTop` methods of the canvas class. From there you can use the shape's width and height to place your white little rectangles.